# js.readFileSync read empty (JSON.parse err) while watching json file modified from python

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, json, fs

I use node.js to write a server.js file,
and it will watch the json file modified by python every second.

If the file was modified, the server will read this json file and print it out.
It will work.
But the error of JSON.parse: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input happens sometimes.

Here's my file generation code with python.

```
di = {"lon":str(0),"lat":str(0)}
iteration = 0
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    lon = np.random.randint(-180, high=180)
    lat = np.random.randint(-90, high=90)
    di["lon"] = str(lon)
    di["lat"] = str(lat)
    with open('./generate.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(di, f, ensure_ascii=False)
    
    # with open(f'./{iteration}.json', 'w') as f:
    #    json.dump(di, f)
    print(f"Done. iteration: {iteration}, lon: {lon}, lat: {lat}")
    iteration += 1
```

The watching function of my server.js

```
generate_file_path = './navigation/generate.json'

let fsWait = false;
fs.watch(generate_file_path, function(event, filename){
    if (filename && event==='change'){
      if (fsWait) return;
      fsWait = setTimeout(()=>{
        fsWait = false;
      }, 100);
      let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(generate_file_path, 'utf8');
      try{
        let g_file = JSON.parse(rawdata);
        console.log(g_file);
      }catch (e){
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
});
```

And the error will like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MUSC.png)

[image]

I found that it might be a readfile problem.
I changed my server code like this.

```
let fsWait = false;
fs.watch(generate_file_path, function(event, filename){
  if (filename && event==='change'){
    if (fsWait) return;
    fsWait = setTimeout(()=>{
      fsWait = false;
    }, 100);
    let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(generate_file_path, 'utf8');
    try{
      // let g_file = JSON.parse(rawdata);
      console.log(rawdata);
    }catch (e){
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
});
```

And it will sometimes print nothing.
[image]

The right hand side is python generation log, left hand side is server.js.
(iteration 7, 10, 17 was missing that read by server.js)

I've tried modified the sleep time of python but the error of reading empty file still exists.
Since the fs.readFileSync sometimes works and sometimes fails, I don't know how to debug this kind of issue.

Comment: Haven't yet. I stuck at the fs.readFileSync problem. It will sometimes read an empty file just like the post above.

Answer (score 0):

The watch triggers multiple times. That's why you need the setTimeout. Just move the reading into the setTimeout so that it doesn't get caught by the other events.

```
let fsWait = false;
fs.watch(generate_file_path, function(event, filename){
  if (filename && event==='change'){
    if (fsWait) return;
    fsWait = setTimeout(()=>{
      fsWait = false;
      let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(generate_file_path, 'utf8');
      try{
        // let g_file = JSON.parse(rawdata);
        console.log(rawdata);
      }catch (e){
        console.log(e);
      }


    }, 100);
  }
});
```